# Download of big gis data

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for data that contains lat/longs such as shipping or flight data that I can use for testing some analysis tools. Ideally, I"m looking for 100 million plus records if possible.

The data doesn't have to be free but would prefer. If anyone knows of any available datasets please let me know.

Comment: Not sure of big enough, but see http://openflights.org/data.html for airport, airline and route data

Comment: @MarkusN you should post that as an answer

Comment: ok will do that now

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Geolife Trajectories dataset from MS Research. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13/
Its open and free as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the GPX dump from OpenStreetMap 
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.gpx

It has all the public traces uploaded by community members.

Answer (score 2):

Please check http://openflights.org/data.html for airports, airlines and route data.

The data are available under the Open Database License. For an example of usage, see e.g. this blog article: http://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique records, but not necessarily unique locations, this is a choice:

http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/

You may have to geocode the airports, maybe the link above by @markusN helps with that:

http://openflights.org/data.html